# Lifespan of a struct within C program

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following structs:

```
typedef struct plane_t Plane;
struct plane_t{
    Point p1;
    Point p2;
    Point p3;
};

typedef struct arrangement_t* Arrangement;
struct arrangement_t{
    //TODO add fields here
    int maxPlanes;
    int curPlanes;
    Plane *planes;
};
```

And I have the following function:

```
Plane planeCreate(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3){

    Plane newPlane = {{point1.x, point1.y, point1.z}, {point2.x, point2.y, point2.z}, {point3.x, point3.y, point3.z}};
    return newPlane;
}
```

Suppose that I'm writing a function which adds a plane into the array planes within arrangment_t struct.

Can I do the following:

```
arrangement->planes[arrangement->curPlanes] = planeCreate(plane.x, plane.y plane.z);
```

Or this struct will "disappear" after exiting this function meaning that I have to it the following way:

```
arrangement->planes[arrangement->curPlanes] = malloc(sizeof(struct plane_t));
    arrangement->planes[arrangement->curPlanes].x=plane.x;
    arrangement->planes[arrangement->curPlanes].x=plane.y;
    arrangement->planes[arrangement->curPlanes].x=plane.z;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it won't disappear. C functions return objects **by value,** so the struct will be **copied** over.

Furthermore,

```
arrangement->planes[arrangement->curPlanes] = malloc(sizeof(struct plane_t));
```

wouldn't even compile - `arrangement->planes[arrangement->curPlanes]` is not a pointer but a struct. If it was a pointer, then your code would work, provided you change the assignment to

```
arrangement->planes[arrangement->curPlanes]->x = plane.x;
```

(accessing a member of a struct pointed to by `p` is done using the `->` operator, not with `.`)

---

What you are probably talking about is not returning the local variable itself, but a **pointer** to it. For example, this:

```
int *wrong_function()
{
    int answer = 42;
    return &answer;
}
```

is erroneous - the `answer` variable is out of scope when the function returns, and its address is invalid (so the above would invoke undefined behavior).

Answer (score 4):

The structure will not "disappear" since you are returning it by *value* (in fact the structure will be copied), and not by *reference* (pointer).

Comment: Right. To be precise, the local object `newPlane` does disappear, but the `return` statement returns a copy of its value. It's no different in principle from `int x = 42; return x;`

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks I've add a precision about the copy.

Answer (score 0):

"Determining how long a variable will be kept is another problem that perplexes
aspiring programmers. Let’s look at the keyword modifier static. This modifier has
several purposes that, unfortunately, are related."
use static .... like nlife {5} since When static is used on a variable found within a function or block, it tells the compiler never to discard or reallocate the variable. The variable is created at compile time and is initialized to zero. The opposite of static in this situation is auto (the
default). That variable, found inside a function or block, is reallocated every time the function or block is entered.

```
/* LIFETIME, written 15 May 1992 by Peter D. Hipson */
/* An example of variable lifetime. */
#include <stdio.h> // Make includes first part of file
#include <string.h>
int nLife = {5}; // Initialize to 5, default is 0.
int main(void); // Define main() and the fact that this program doesn’t
// use any passed parameters.
void DisplayLife(void); // Define DisplayLife()
int main()
{
int nCounter = 0;
do
{
int nCountLoop = 0; /* This nCounter is unique to the loop */
nCountLoop += 3; /* Increments (and prints) the loop’s
nCounter */

nLife += nCounter;
printf(“nCountLoop is = %d\n”, nCountLoop);
}
while (++nCounter < 10); /* Increments the function’s nCounter */
DisplayLife();
printf(“Ended, nCounter is = %d\n”, nCounter);
return (0);
}
void DisplayLife()
{
printf(“DisplayLife(), nLife = %d?\n”, nLife);
}
```

In LIFETIME.C, the variable nLife is known to both main() and DisplayLife().
This sharing of the variable is an acceptable programming practice and is commonly
used as outlined previously.
In the preceding example, if the declaration of nLife had been the following:
static int nLife = {5}; // Initialize to 5, default is zero.
the result would have been the same. The reason is that only one source file is in this program; therefore, nLife had to be visible in only one file. Whenever possible, remember to make your external variables static: If they are known in only one source file, they are much less likely to be modified unintentionally by another function in a different source file.

```
typedef struct plane_t Plane;
struct plane_t{
Point p1;
Point p2;
Point p3;
};

typedef struct arrangement_t* Arrangement;
struct arrangement_t{
//TODO add fields here
int maxPlanes;
int curPlanes;
Plane *planes;
};
```

maybe since void DisplayLife(void) is seperate from the main(void) you could set the nlife+=nCounter outside of the void DisplayLife() and pass the values from the plane and arrangement struct that way.... hey i may be wrong call me out on anything i can take a beating =(